# Wordpress Mail()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the below code to send the mail in wordpress using PHP code. When I use `info@xyz.com =`, its working fine for me, but when I use `info@xyz.net`, I am not able to send mail. But in front end I am getting success message. Can anybody help me please?

```
$to      = 'support@xyz.net';
$subject = $_POST["subject"];
$message = $_POST["message"] . "\n\n<br/>" . $_POST["name"];
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: info@xyz.net' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: info@xyz.net' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
echo "Your request was successfully sent. Thank you!";
}
else{
    echo "Failed to send your request. Please try later!";
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear, the code you've quoted has zero relevance to Wordpress; it's pure PHP, without any WP dependencies at all.

Comment: It's probably because your server is not identify as permitted send by the domaine xyz.net (by some [SPF record](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax)) and so it end up in spam. So it's not a PHP issue, more probably a domain set up issue.

Comment: You are supressing the errors of the one function that you want to see the errors for.  Remove the `@` from `@mail()` it may give you a clue.